# How to choose neural network architecture for a relatively small dataset with less than 10 features for regression?

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, neural-network, linear-regression

How to go about selecting an architecture for a dataset with 80 datapoints and 9 features for a regression model?

Working on the Desarhnais [dataset](http://promise.site.uottawa.ca/SERepository/datasets/desharnais.arff), with "Effort" as the target variable.

Would a simple NN with one hidden layer suffice since the data is not large or overly complicated?
Thinking of using ReLU as the activation function since it is a form of linear regression model, but unsure how to select number of neurons in the hidden layer.

Any tips and advice would be helpful.

Comment: How do you figure that ReLU is a form of linear regression? // I don’t think $80$ points is enough to do any serious work with a neural network, anyway. If you just want to learn the mechanics of coding up your model, though, then that is fine.

Comment: I thought of it like this : in linear regression we find ideal coefficients for each attribute, in a polynomial sense) at least, so the network weights act as coefficients and relu inside a neurons helps in computing the dot product of the weights with the input and passes it on

Comment: Do you mean that the neural network acts like a linear regression on the final hidden layer?

Comment: Yes, that was kind of my intuition. Like a stacked linear regression model

Comment: That’s a good way to think of it, but that works for any activation function, not just ReLU.

Comment: I will explore other activations functions as well. Thank you

Comment: Any tips/advice how to proceed with the architecture due to the constrained dataset size ?

Comment: I would advise against a neural network of any kind. Why do you want to use a neural network?

Answer (score 1):

With such a small dataset, first use the simplest: linear regression. Otherwise, you risk overfitting. If linear regression does not work properly, think of why and choose a different option.